# Bug with `badges/name` endpoint

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, api-v2.2, badges

Last night I had a programme running and it errored on the first call to the `badges/name` endpoint on the API, exact API endpoint call:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges/name?order=asc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=1
```

Response:

```
{"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}
```

First occurrence: approximately 00:00UTC+00:00
Most recent occurrence: 06:17UTC+00:00

Update: this is back, has been happening for several days for me now, latest at 00:05UTC+00:00 on 18 January 2017. This only happens when I set `pagesize=100`.

Verified with and without application key. Verified from three independent IP addresses (and computers).

API docs recommend posting a question on Stack Apps, so here it is.

Comment: Confirmed.  Setting either the `pagesize` parameter, or `page` > 1, seems to trigger the bug.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for investigating that! I was attempting to, but I kept getting a `throttle_violation` and gave up.

Comment: @BrockAdams This issue is back.

Comment: Huh?  I didn't know it was ever *not* back. ;)  Anywho, an SE developer will have to fix this.

Comment: @BrockAdams It got fixed last time shortly after reported here, which was *still* multiple days after it started.

Comment: The first time this happened was around the time that the [Not A Robot badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win) was introduced, this time it's around the time that the [Census badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge) was introduced. Coincidence?

Comment: [Per comment of @Oded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341926/census-badge-link-404s/341928#comment435360_341928), this has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for sure what the original problem was, but the most recent issue was a result of implementing [a new badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge) without rebuilding the API. Once the API was pushed to production, the bug was resolved. If it happens again (especially if there's a new badge) please let me (or really any employee) know. We can contact a developer directly.

---

From [a comment on a related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341926/census-badge-link-404s/341928#comment435402_341928):

> Fundamentally the problem is that the API can remain broken without us really paying attention to it. I appreciate your report since it prompted us to rebuild the API. (That was the immediate problem this time around.) But **we shouldn't really be relying on user reports for this sort of thing.**
>
> **We need to start [treating our products as a platform](https://plus.google.com/+RipRowan/posts/eVeouesvaVX).** We don't treat our API as mission critical. There's good reasons for that, but it's going to hurt us if we don't sort it out eventually. (Summary: sorry about that. We can do better.)

Comment: I thought your comment made for a better answer.  I hope that's okay.